# I would like to use a previously set javascript var inside of the XPath. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, xpath

My `xpath` target format looks like this:

```
//a[@id='info_0_link']
```

I would like to use a previously set `javascript` var inside of the `xpath` here:

```
var nextNum = 0;
//a[@id='info_'+nextNum+'_link']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the concatenation to the Javascript string that holds the xpath.

```
var xpath = "//a[@id='info_" + nextNum + "_link']"
```